# Pandas: How to combine nunique and sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am working with a dataframe similar to this:

`id year    losses  revenue expenses
2   2014    1500    5000    400
1   2013    1000    2000    5600
1   2018    500 10000   2100
3   2019    1500    15000   500
2   2011    100 2100    500
4   2010    1200    400 2000
4   2014    1000    22000   1000`

I would like to sort by the unique values in the `id` column and find the sum of `losses` `revenue` and `expenses` My desired result would like like

`id losses  revenue expenses
2   1600    7100    900
1   1500    12000   7700
3   1500    15000   500
4   2200    22400   3000`

I tried using

`df.groupby('id')['losses', 'revenue', 'expenses'].sum().reset_index()`

but that returns more columns than it should. I tried to utilize `nunique()` to get the unique values for `id` then get the sums of the remaining columns from that, but am struggling to find a way for that to work

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False)[['losses', 'revenue', 'expenses']].sum()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameters `sort=False` and `as_index=False` to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
df = df.groupby('id', sort=False, as_index=False)['losses', 'revenue', 'expenses'].sum()
print (df)
   id  losses  revenue  expenses
0   2    1600     7100       900
1   1    1500    12000      7700
2   3    1500    15000       500
3   4    2200    22400      3000
```